# Forward-propagating SQL data into new rows

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

So I have data in five minute intervals from one source and one minute intervals from another source. What I have done is load the five minute interval data into a some sqlite tables with relationships between the various data types. The tables have a column for the one-minute data as well. Now, what I would like to do is find the one-minute data that matches the five-minute data, update that row, and then forward-propagate the five-minute data into new rows for the one-minute data.

I.e. -

```
            DB before                          DB after
    row  [time] [1-min] [5-min]        row  [time] [1-min] [5-min]
          5-t0    null    d0                 5-t0     m0      d0
          5-t1    null    d1                 1-t1     m1      d0
                  ...                        1-t2     m2      d0
                                             1-t3     m3      d0
                                             5-t1     m4      d1
```

and so on.

The problem is that the function I am using to do this is *very* slow. As in, slower than molasses on a cold winter day slow. I am new to sql operations and sqlalchemy, so any critique of my function will be greatly appreciated. Here is what I have:

```
import glob
import gc
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, and_
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, exc, lazyload
from metar import Metar
from db_models import Base, BaseObservation, SkyObservation





def w_convertion(w_str):
    if w_str == 'No Data':
        return None
    else:
        return float(w_str)

def db_update(W_PATH):
    with open(W_PATH) as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)

        for line in reader:
            time = datetime.strptime(line['time'], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
            qry = session.query(BaseObservation).\
                  options(lazyload(BaseObservation.sky_observations))

            try:
                result = qry.filter_by(time=time).one()
                if result.W:
                    pass
                setattr(result, 'W', w_convertion(line['W']))
                session.commit()

            except exc.MultipleResultsFound:
                print('More than one result. Skipped {}'.format(time))
                pass

            except exc.NoResultFound:       
                dt = timedelta(minutes=(time.minute % 5))
                t = (time - dt)

                # find previous observation
                try:
                    result = qry.filter_by(time=t).one()
                    keeper_dict = dict( (k, v) for k,v in result.__dict__.items() if k in keepers )

                    # make new observation with previous data
                    obs = BaseObservation(**keeper_dict)
                    setattr(obs, 'time', time)
                    setattr(obs, 'W', w_convertion(line['W']))
                    session.add(obs)
                    session.flush()

                    # link new observation to sky observations
                    for sky_obs in result.sky_observations:
                        sky_obs.base_observations.append(obs)

                    session.commit()

                except exc.NoResultFound:
                    print('No previous weather obs found for {}. Point skipped.'.format(time))
                    pass


        gc.collect()
        print('W additions done.')
```

Comment: 1. Use SQLAlchemy Core instead of ORM if you want performance. 2. You need to batch your queries together, i.e. make one or two queries for every `n` (`n` = 100, 1000, etc) lines in `reader`, not for every single line.

Comment: Why are you calling `commit()` for every row?